# Finding the transpose of a very, very large matrix

Tags: computer-science, transpose, large-data

I have this huge 2 dimensional array of data.  It is stored in row order:

A(1,1) A(1,2) A(1,3) ..... A(n-2,n) A(n-1,n) A(n,n)

I want to rearrange it into column order

A(1,1) A(2,1) A(3,1) ..... A(n,n-2) A(n,n-1) A(n,n)

The data set is rather large - more than will fit on the RAM on a computer.  (n is about 10,000, but each data item takes about 1K of space.)

Does anyone know slick or efficient algorithms to do this?

Comment: What programming language/application?

Comment: Where is the matrix stored if it is too big to be stored in RAM? Things are stored in RAM during execution.

Comment: n=10000 means 10000x10000x1KB = 100 GB.

Comment: Do you want to transpose in-place or do you want to write a transposed version of the data in a new file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `n` empty files (reserve enough space for `n` elements, if you can). Iterate through your original matrix. Append element `(i,j)` to file `j`. Once you are done with that, append the files you just wrote.

Comment: I think the "n empty" files is not such a good idea.  You have to create about 10,000 files.  Some file systems don't even allow that many files in a directory, and others use unsophisticated database techniques to list the files in a directory.  So first of all you need to use some very smart file system that uses B-trees or something like that to list its directories.  (Maybe some of the linux file systems do this.)

Comment: Next, when you write to the files, you will be writing to about 10,000 different places on your hard drive in a round robin manner.  This most likely will completely clobber any disk caching scheme used either by the operating system, or the disk hardware.  And this problem will persist even if if you have one file with n empty slots pre-reserved.

Comment: On the other hand, a friend of mine sent me an email in which he actually tried this method, and it really did go faster than I thought it would.  So i take back what I said - your solution is definitely worth trying.

Comment: I haven't tried it out yet myself, because you have to adjust settings on the computer so that you can have 10,000 open files at the same time.  And I can only do this by rebooting the computer.

Comment: So my apologies for criticizing what turns out to be an excellent solution.

Comment: No harm done; I actually did not think about the issues you point out. I just figured it might be a no-brain solution until OS/hardware limits are reached. Can't you create a (software) buffer as big as your memory, reducing disk IO operations significantly? Writing every single cell to disk on its own is certainly not a good idea. Regarding file systems: Well, use a proper one (I have *no* expertise in this area, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 3):

You need a Matrix class, such that your whole app accesses a matrix through an instance of the class. Then a transpose can just be setting a flag that reverses the indexes when accessing an element. Instant transpose!

Comment: The data will be stored in a file on a hard drive.  I want a program that reads this file, and writes the transpose of the data onto another file.

Comment: Also, I probably exaggerated the size specifications of the file.  It will probably be closer to 10GB than 100GB.  But definitely more than 4GB.

Comment: Finally, I am thinking of writing this program in C++.

Comment: But to give some idea - one thing I just thought of doing was writing a large data file where each line is "i j A(j,i)" and then running the unix sort command on it (i and j would include leading zeros so that they have the same length as text).  I must admit that I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Why `n*log(n)` if you can have `n`?

Answer (score 0):

The naïve way is to just read through the file 10000 times and find the corresponding columns for each row. This should be easy to implement but I don't know how much time it will take to run the program.

<strike>In your comments you mentioned outputing another file which you then should sort with `sort`. That's a bad idea since it will take forever to sort such a large file. Sorting is a complex (or at least resource-heavy) problem, so generalizing the transpose into a sort is probably the wrong way to do it.</strike>

Comment: Regarding the sort idea - I have done experiments with it, and the unix sort program is rather sophisticated.  For example, if the file is unbelievably huge, it splits it up into lots of smaller files, sorts each of them, and then merges them.  I have tested it with files way larger than the RAM on the computer, and it does perform rather well.

Comment: That's called a divide-and-conquer method and is basically what mergesort and quicksort is doing (though most of the time you divide the problem in memory, not on disk, but the basic principle is the same).

Comment: By the way, I take back what I said about linear time. Traversing the file will be in quadratic time (longer file multiplied by more iterations), so I guess the sorting method seems like a viable solution after all.

Comment: Regarding the quicksort algorithm - yes, I was at first thinking along the lines of writing a divide and conquer algorithm to do the transpose.  But I began to realize that the bookkeeping would be hard.  And then I thought - you know, those unix guys have already done this hard work - let's not reinvent the wheel.