# Change the format of csv file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I done some research but could not find a better solution to change the format of the csv file. 
I want to convert row of csv file to column, and convert column to row.

for example:

original csv file:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
7,6,5,6,4,2,1
```

I want to convert above file as

```
a,1,7
b,2,6
c,3,5
d,4,4
e,5,3
f,6,2
g,7,1
```

Is there any easier solutions?

Comment: easiest: just do the conversion. `open_csv.process { |nya| out }`

Comment: @Smar thank you , i am not able to find .process from the DOC of the ruby 1.9.3. i have to use this version of ruby. is it available with this version.

Comment: *"could not find a better solution"* / *"Is there any easier solutions?"* - better and easier than what? Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Stefan Sorry for the way of asking question, i will give detailed information next time.

Comment: @Rustam don't hesitate to edit your question, regardless of whether you have accepted an answer or not. If you have already found a way to transpose a CSV file, please share it. It can be helpful and valuable for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to transpose this data

```
transposed = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv").transpose

CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "w") do |csv|
  transposed.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

1. Read the data
2. Transpose it - Ruby 1.9.3 should know `#transpose`
3. Write it back

It's dead simple, provided your csv isn't too big to be read at once.

If it is, though, it's becomes quite a horror. If that's the case, refer to answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512335/finding-the-transpose-of-a-very-very-large-matrix).

Comment: I'd like to know line length of a file that is too big to be opened like this :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't really understand what you mean, I read whole file into memory, as this is needed to call `#transpose`. If file weights few gigs, it is likely to produce _unexpected results_. Now, holding that much data in a file is a bad idea, but every now and than such things happen.

Comment: @Borsunho  Thank you this works and exactly what i looked for.